# Blackberry: Not able to get locations  SDCard/Media Card as fileSystemRoot?

Tags: blackberry

I want to openOrCreate database in SDcard / Media Card. When i run the application in device (BlackBerry Curve 8900), i find only one root i.e "system/" and running application in simulator (9500), i find three roots as shown in comment in code. I am getting error at;

```
  _db = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(_uri); 
  (error: Method "toString" with signature "()Ljava/lang/String;" is not applicable on this object)
```

And i am not able to understand what is this error about. 
Here is the code.

```
public void getValues() throws Exception
{

    boolean sdCardPresent = false;
    String root = null;
    Enumeration e = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
    while (e.hasMoreElements())
    {
        root = (String)e.nextElement();
        System.out.println("Value of root::" +root); // value of root = "system/" when run in device and
                                                     // value of root = "store/" "SDCard/" "system/" when run in simulator 
        if(root.equalsIgnoreCase("system/"))
        {
            sdCardPresent = true;
        }     
    }         
    System.out.println("--------------------getValues()----------------------------------");
    URI _uri = URI.create(Global.DB_PATH + Global.DB_Main);
    System.out.println("Valud of uri::" +_uri);
    _db = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(_uri); //getting error here. 
    System.out.println("Valud of _db::" +_db);
    _db.close();
```

I tried these three paths, getting output with "/store"(when run in simulator) but error with rest two paths.Even using "/store" in device is showing the same error.

```
Global.DB_PATH = "/MediaCard/databases/";
Global.DB_PATH = "/SDCard/databases/";
Global.DB_PATH = "/store/databases/";
```

Is there any way how to get SDCard/Media Card as root so that i can copy the database in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is when you are running your app on a real device you have USB cable plugged in to the device. If this is the case, try to unplug the cable and rerun the app. You may use `Dialog.inform()` to quickly check what roots you get this time.

Comment: yes sir, your guess is right, as per your advice i unplugged the cable and got the sdcard location. I am now able to create the database in SDCard.Thank you very much.

Comment: That's just BlackBerry.. :( Consider creating some logger that writes log entries to a file, which you can later pull down from device to PC for investigation.

Comment: Guys, when downvoting please also state a reason. This way I can learn smth from the case so I will not repeat the same mistake next time. Otherwise this just a childish/dishonest action. I can always accept my mistakes without any vindictive feedback.

Comment: Fixed my problem :) I think its due to having it plugged in with USB Drive. So the Card is connected to PC and unaccesable via phone. Connect your phone, run in any mode. Then manually eject the storage drives from "my computer". This way, you are connected by cable, and not using the storage drives via pc. And hence can run DEBUG mode.

Answer (score -1):

```
    private ObjectListField getFileList() {
    if (fileList == null) {
        fileList = new ObjectListField();
        String[] roots = new String[3];
        Enumeration enum = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
        int x = 0;
        while (enum.hasMoreElements()) {
            if (x < 3) {
                roots[x] = enum.nextElement().toString();
            }
            x++;
        }
        enum = FileSystemRegistry.listRoots();
        fileList.set((roots[2] != null) ? roots : new String[]{"system/", "SDCard/", "store/"});
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Try this code.

Comment: my question is that i am not getting fileroots i.e i am not getting SDCard/ or Media Card in root as shown in code. When i am running the application in device i figured out only one root ie. system/ even if sdcard is inserted. (enum.hasMoreElements() loops only once giving root = system/).